# Duplicate Attributes of table SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, attributes

I have a table like:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4
------------
1  2   3  6
23 55  4  7
2  3   7  8
```

What would be the query to double the columns and sum 1 to other values like:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4  a5 a6 a7 a8
-------------------------
1  2   3  6  2  3   4  7
23 55  4  7  24 56  5  8
2  3   7  8  3  4   8  9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my assumption is correct (see my comment), then use this query:

```
SELECT
     a1, a2, a3, a4,
     a1 + 1 AS 'a5',
     a2 + 1 AS 'a6',
     a3 + 1 AS 'a7',
     a4 + 1 AS 'a8'
FROM
     dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: and to create other table with that attributes I would do: `SELECT
     a1, a2, a3, a4,
     a1 + 1 AS 'a5',
     a2 + 1 AS 'a6',
     a3 + 1 AS 'a7',
     a4 + 1 AS 'a8' INTO NEWtable
FROM myTable`  ?

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
select a1, a2, a3, a4,
a1 +1 as a5, a2 +1 as a6, a3 +1 as a7,  a4 + 1 as a8
from SomeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a magic way to do that without spelling it out:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
(
    a1 INT,
    a2 INT,
    a3 INT,
    a4 INT
);

INSERT @x VALUES
(1,2,3,6),
(23,55,4,7),
(2,3,7,8);

SELECT a1, a2, a3, a4, 
    a5 = a1 + 1, a6 = a2 + 1,
    a7 = a3 + 1, a8 = a4 + 1
FROM @x;
```